# Distribution of the sample mean of a Rayleigh random variable

Tags: distributions, sample, rayleigh-distribution

Let $\{X_1,X_2,X_3\ldots,X_n\}$ be a random sample from a Rayleigh distribution with shape parameter $b$. Let $\bar{X}=(1/n)\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ denote the sample mean.

QUESTION 1: What is the distribution of $\bar{X}$?

QUESTION 2: Is there a known relation between the mean of the distribution of $\bar{X}$ (denoted here by $\mu_{\bar{X}}$) and the (population) mean of the Rayleigh random variable $X$ (denoted here by $\mu_X$, and equal to $b\sqrt{\pi/2}$).

**EDIT: Omit Question (2); the answer is self-evident.**

QUESTION 3: If ${X}$ is a Rayleigh random variable, then what is the distribution of ${X}/\bar{X}$?

If the answers to these questions are known, please supply a reference. If they are not, then please suggest an efficient method from mathematical statistics for obtaining them.

Comment: I do not understand what (2) is asking, because the mean of $\bar X$ must equal the common mean of the $X_i$.  What, then, does "$X$" refer to?

Comment: As I've said above, $X$ is a Rayleigh random variable. $\bar{X}$ is a statistic (a function of one or more random variables). Each has a distribution its own right with separate means and variances. Question (2) is asking whether or not there is a known analytical relationship between $\mu_{X}$ and $\mu_{\bar{X}}$.

Comment: Although you *called* "$X$" a Rayleigh RV, you did not explain its connection with the $X_i$.  It still seems superfluous.  This issue, as well as the language about samples and populations may be a stumbling block for you, for otherwise why isn't it immediately obvious that the mean of $\bar X$ must equal the mean of each of the $X_i$?

Comment: You're right. I was overlooking the obvious in Question (2). Any thoughts on Question (1)? What I am ultimately after is the following: If ${X}$ has a Rayleigh distribution, then what is the distribution of ${X}/\bar{X}$? I will therefore scratch Question (2), and add my ultimate question.

Comment: Question (3) needs to be made more precise: are $X$ and $\bar X$ assumed to be independent or not?  As far as I can tell, you won't be able to find any nice way to express the distribution of $\bar X$. Perhaps the best you can do is recognize that its characteristic function will be a product of confluent hypergeometric functions.

Comment: You should explain what you want to do. There might be no closed form for the densities you're considering, but depending on your needs, some approximations can be proposed.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019375/distribution-of-sum-of-independent-rayleigh-random-variables

Comment: Paper giving approximations:  https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1388722,   https://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.3539.pdf